# I need to replace special characters like (-) into text file in a line start with CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I need to replace special characters like (-) into text file in a line start with CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST
For Example :

```
Create table if not exists "abc-xyz" (
col1 int,
col2 string );
Create table if not exists "xyz abc" (
col3 int,
col2=4 float);
```

The output i need :

```
Create table if not exists "abc_xyz" (
col1 int,
col2 string );
Create table if not exists "xyz_abc" (
col3 int,
col2=4 float);
```

Comment: Have a look at `sed`.

Comment: In the second create table line is no dash; why should there be a substitution as well?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `awk` also:

```
 awk ' {if($0 ~ /Create table/) {gsub("-", "_", $0); print} else print $0}' text.file
```

Comment: This will replace all dashes on all lines. The OP appears to want to replace them only on certain lines (which is easy) and inside quoted strings (which is slightly harder in the trivial case, and in the most general case requires a full-blown SQL parser).

Comment: In this case I'd use some other language like python or scala, not bash

Comment: Edited the command. But looks not so nice as for me.

Comment: The edited version isn't correct either: The lines need to **start** with `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST`, while you test for the occurance of `Create table` at any position in a line.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily target the lines you want to match with either `sed` or Awk. If you want the matching to be case-insensitive, Awk is probably better.

```
sed '
  # If this is not one of the targeted lines, just skip the rest of the script
  /Create table if not exists /!b
  # Label for loop
  :0
  # Is there a quoted string on this line with a space or a dash?
  # If no, we are done; again, skip to the end of the script
  /^\([^"]*"[^ -"]*\)[ -]/!b
  # If yes, replace it (s//.../ reuses the previous regex)
  s//\1_/
  # and loop back and check if there are still some left
  b0' file.txt
```

Awk is also significantly more succinct for this case.

```
awk -F '"' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS }
  tolower($0) ~ /create table if not exists / {
    gsub(/[ -]/, "_", $2) } 1' file.txt
```

This targets the quoted string by setting the field separator to a double quote (`-F '"'`) and then performing a substitution only in the second field (i.e. inside the quoted string).

(If you are a Windows victim, single quotes probably won't work; but what does work at all is a good question. Finding an operating system which actually works is what I always recommend.)

This assumes that you have a fairly predictable use of whitespace etc in your SQL syntax; for the general case, you need a proper SQL parser rather than a simple regular expression tool to properly handle SQL code (and the idea to programmatically modify those files is dubious anyway; a better solution then is probably to have the input in a properly machine-readable format and generate SQL from that).

Comment: I think the pattern should be `/^create table if not exists /`....

Comment: @user1934428 Probably; I didn't want to make assumptions about leading whitespace etc but if the pattern is always at beginning of line, by all means add the `^` anchor.